# Нужна помощь в расшифровке текста методом частотного анализа

Tags: криптография

**Цель:** взлом шифра простой замены методом частотного анализа;
**Задание к работе:** вскрыть предложенный шифротекст, найти ключ и открытый текст;
**Методика выполнения работы:**

1. Посчитать частоты символов, встречающихся в шифротетсте.
2. Сделать первую замену.
3. На основе читаемости некоторых кусков текста произвести корректировку замен.
4. Сделать правильную замену и прочитать открытый текст.

(*Шифротекст приведен ниже*)

Как решал я:

- С помощью самописной программы на Python определил частоту повторения символов в шифротексте, произвел замену символов и получил "расшифрованный" текст (Опять набор букв).
- Затем в "расшифрованном" тексте искал слова, с помощью которых пытался составить ключ для расшифровки (алфавит), заменить буквы из алфавита в шифротекст и получить осмысленный результат. (Этому пункту нас "учили" институте)

Второй пункт, по идее, это как менять "шило на мыло". То есть, бессмыслица. Уже и не знаю, что теперь делать. Может, найдутся знатоки и помогут с данным вопросом :)

**Зашифрованный текст:**
ющдэюмчцжшмнмжыюкдгьяньгььфидкнюофьеддюкдбщьэоыжеоцдшхечфьюскдэгддюшойьньэохадэпошоэмйобфьеьшймкыоажюкдбюньекнлбюхыошлбфовцойобюкбьажеошоедкншжтмжэоыоаюоькношьюжювжксюшжцондесшььгехшмеоксшоцдшхжньнрокщькедяньгьщьтдеьюоеокюьчкьфорймьшофлеоьрдшсшдбьэьвокьфьзэлпобмаошдюдежйоэькньцшдцшьгьйэжюьфьйорньдидфьеддадеоеьшдйэокжюлцддшдйэокжюьдежтьфлеокнэошшохщэжрдкйокщэьфьэьцкфьймьашожындбщэжрдкьййьньэлдщэжамцлюочнаехкдфхщедвжюлдпдшижшлйойхшжкноэоекхюмгьашькнскюьдцмаэмгмхшдцьгюшдзшознжшжьашьзйэокжюьзрдэнлаопдйоэждгеоыоддбьнхжюлэопоювждаьфэьамвждфлежкежвйьццоелжнмкйелжэдвжндесшьшдбьэьвжаопдэмйжянобоэойндэжкнжрдкйохрдэнобьнхжшдфьесвжджшдамэшьзуьэцлфлежйэокшлжвдэвоюлйьгаохюкедаыошжцжюьвдешондээокмжкйечрохюоэдшсйжкдкнэлацжнэжхйьньэохньесйьюшжцондесшьщькцьнэдеошоцдшхкюьжцжфьесвжцжндцшькдэлцжгеоыоцжйопаохжыаоцкйоыоеоцшдшдкйьесйькеьющэдпадрдцьшжкшьюоюыхежйопаохкюьчэофьнмоюоэдшсйоюкембшороеоржнонсйшжгмйьньэмчьшоадэпоеомкдфхшойьедшхбыоеьпжющоестдцйшхгжшхцоэсхжюошьюшофлеоюлкьйохкнэьзшохпдшижшоеднкьэьйодзцьпшьфлфлеьаонсфьесвдкмахщьфмйехцщьемкдалбюьеькьнйэьюдшшьюлкноюедшшлбжыщьардщтошьщькюдпдцмрэдыюлрозшьшдпшьцмщьрнжфдыцьэижшежтмюькьфдшшькнжпдщьпжюьцмюдкдеьцмфедкймфьесвжбгеоыдзйоыоеьксгьэоыаьцдшсвдгеоыомшддфлежйоэждьрдшсьнйэлнлдгмфлкежвйьцньшйждшдцшьгькнэьгждшькаьюьесшьщэоюжесшлзжшдцшьгьшоедюмчкньэьшмэмйомшддфлеофдыйьедтфьесвохщьрнжцмпкйохкщэдйэокшлцжщэьаьегьюонлцжщоестоцжшошдзфлеьндцшькжшддыойэлньдщеонсдйэдщйькнхгжюочиддддкнэьзшмчждидцьеьамчноежчйьньэьзьшоюжажцьидгьехеоьшокжадеорэдыюлрозшьщэхцьжвжеойойьдньщеонсдйьгаохюьвдешогоедэдчьшоюыхеоцьчэмймщэжнхшмеоцдшхйкдфдйойфманькпдеошждцэоккцьнэднсцдшхщьфежпджкйоыоеоюыгехшмюшоцдшхндцпдшдкйьесйьбьеьашлцьнйэ

**Диаграмма распределения символов по процентному отношению:**
[image: диаграмма]

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка. Если исходить из того, что текст зашифрован методом подстановочной таблицы, то нужно сопоставить буквы по частоте использования в этом тексте и в среднем в языке. Скорее всего, самой часто встречающейся букве в шифротексте будет соответствовать самая часто используемая в языке, и так далее.

Comment: Я подставил символы по такому порядку и получил "расшифрованный" текст. Однако, опять наполненный несвязными между собой символами

Comment: Так нужно представить код, исходные данные и результат.

Comment: А ещё можно ручками поменять неправильные символы. Это же статистика, тут нельзя быть уверенным в результате.

Comment: простите не специалиста, а соотнести полученную диаграмму с частотой букв в русском языке - никак? Дешифровать текст в первом приближении и потом ручной коррекцией направить алгоритм туда куда нужно. На крайний случай - взять любой сравнительно большой русский текст и просто построить свою диаграмму и соотнести по буквам с полученной?

Comment: @Ingvar об этом и написано выше. Итак, я сделал такую операцию, но результат нечитаемый. Нужны идеи. Я бы пересчитал частотную таблицу из условия.

Comment: Я несколько раз проверил таблицу частот символов в зашифрованном тексте на правильность. Всё правильно.
Есть ли такой вариант, что текст попросту нельзя расшифровать?

Comment: Мне вот даже самому интересно стало. А Вы уверены, что это именно подстановочный шифр? Условия задачи есть, можете запостить ее полностью?

Comment: В посте выложил всё, что у меня есть по поводу задачи. В задаче указано, что это взлом шифра простой замены. Из этого и сделал вывод, что это подстановочный шифр.
Либо я чего-то не понимаю)